# How to "highlight" using text in Vim?

Tags: vim, terminal, syntax-highlighting, neovim

These three lines of Vim script "highlights" all instances of `TODO` in my source code by placing `[[[` and `]]]` around it.

```
:set t_Co=1
:highlight Braces start=[[[ stop=]]]
:call matchadd("Braces", "TODO")
```

Unfortunately, this only works in "normal terminals". This is why I have to set `t_Co` to `1`.

Can something similar be achieved in a color terminal or in gui? (Or in NeoVim?). This could be an extremely useful way of augmenting your code with meta information.

Comment: @JanHudec, what is your t_Co set to by default? `set t_Co?`. For me, it only works if `t_Co` is `1`.

Comment: Why would you prefer this over "normal" highlighting with colors and text attributes? Doesn't this mess up the screen and vertical navigation?

Comment: What is a "normal terminal"? Why do you `set t_Co=1`? What makes you think you can't highlight arbitrary text in something other than a "normal terminal"? Why do you use `highlight` instead of `syntax` in your second line?

Comment: @IngoKarkat: this would convey much more information. For instance at the end of a C class definition, I could write somthing like 'end-of-class' after the closing curly bracket. I would probably only use it for augmentation at the end of the line, so it won't mess up my vertical alignment.

Comment: @romani "normal terminal" is the expression used in the vim documentation `h: highlight-args` and means something like "non-color terminal". My question is not about highlighting text with colors, but "highlighting" text with text. I don't know the pro's and con's for using syntax as you suggest.

Comment: And what does "highlighting text with text" means? Do you mean that you don't care about colors but only about atributes (bold, reverse, etc.)?

Comment: @romainl, in my example above, it means placing some text, namely `[[[` and `]]]` around the text. So in the editor, the text `TODO` would look like this `[[[[TODO]]]`. And I don't care about colour.

Comment: O_o'  Nope, this can only be achieved in "normal terminals". `term`, `start`, and `stop` are completely ignored in "color" contexts.

Comment: Oh, sorry, this actually **never works**. The `start` and `stop` are supposed to emit non-standard *escape sequences*. Printing characters that take space with them is likely to cause problems somewhere in navigation.

Answer (score 4):

Please keep in mind that Vim is a *text editor*; these display the file contents mostly as-is. In order to *augment your code with meta information*, Vim offers:

- (syntax) highlighting: colors and text attributes like bold or italic
- concealment: hide or condense matches to nothing / a single character
- signs (shown in a column left of the window)

Your approach is a **hack that misuses the definition of raw terminal codes**; these are meant to be invisible control sequences interpreted by the terminal, but you send visible text.

As you've found out at `:help highlight-args`:

> ```
> There are three types of terminals for highlighting:
> term      a normal terminal (vt100, xterm)
> cterm     a color terminal (MS-DOS console, color-xterm, these have the "Co"
>           termcap entry)
> gui       the GUI
> ```

The `start=` and `end=` arguments (that your hack relies on) are only supported for "normal terminals", not for *cterm* and *gui*. That's why you have to `:set t_Co=1` (i.e. force a non-color terminal) for this to work.

Because of these downsides (and more: redrawing problems, vertical navigation that's off), I would recommend to drop this, and use one of the "approved" methods listed above. There are so many Vim users, and they seem to be fine with them as well.